# Find the cost of positive tests

Tags: probability, statistics

The employees of a firm that manufactures insulation are being tested for indications of asbestos in their lungs.

The firm is requested to send 5 employees who have positive indications of asbestos on to a medical center for further testing.

If 45% of the employees have positive indications of asbestos in their lungs, find the probability that 10 employees must be tested in order to find 5 positives.

I calculated the answer to be $.117$ which is correct. but the second is:

If each test costs U$50, find the expected value of the total cost of conducting the tests necessary to locate the three positives.

I thought this would be just expectation*50 but it seems to be wrong. Where is my mistake in figuring this out?

Comment: You switched from $5$ positives to $3$ positives.  Was that intentional?

Comment: yes it was. Does it mean I have to find a different expectation?

Comment: Well, sure.  Now you need the expected number of draws to get $3$ "winners".